# Issue installing selnolig under MikTeX

Tags: miktex, selnolig

I'm trying to install selnolig in the MiKTeX 2.9 package manager, but I'm getting this problem report:

```
MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: The operation could not be completed because a required file does not exist.
Data: 
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\PackageInstaller.cpp
Line: 3286
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Microsoft Windows 7 Business Edition, 32-bit Service Pack 1 (build 7601)
Invokers: explorer
SystemAdmin: yes
PowerUser: no
```

What do I do to fix this?

Comment: Could this issue be related to your earlier posting regarding how to update a MikTeX distribution? Did the update process go smoothly, or did you encounter errors? For what it's worth, my acquaintances who run `selnolig` under MikTeX have not (yet!) reported this specific error. (I'm a MacTeX user myself and don't use MikTeX...) Any MikTeX users out there who have encountered this problem?

Comment: Here's what happened. A few days ago I downloaded the package off of CTAN and placed it in my local TeX directory because (if I remember correctly) I didn't see it in the package repository (`C:\proTeXt\MiKTeX\tm\packages`). It worked fine until a little while ago when I updated all updateable packages (which went smoothly); now `selnolig` appears in the package manager as an installable package, but there is no corresponding file in the package repository. The package I downloaded is still there.

Comment: When I try to compile a file that requires `selnolig` and MiKTeX tries to install it on-the-fly, I get the following error in TeXstudio:

    `File: hyperref.sty
    Type: error
    Line: line 5037
    Message: File \`url.sty' not found. \let`

Comment: I'm guessing the reason `selnolig` didn't show up so far in `C:\proTeXt\MiKTeX\tm\packages` is that your "local repository" was probably older than a year, whereas `selnolig` has been on the CTAN -- and hence visible to MikTeX and TeXLive -- for *less than* a year. If you downloaded and installed `selnolig` manually to a "local" tree, you should still be able to run it. The fact that `selnolig` didn't get installed in the "main" tree as well shouldn't be a problem -- at least not until the package's next update comes along... But am I maybe missing something about your setup?

Comment: The error message you report (involving the `hyperref` and `url` style files) doesn't sound like something that might be related to `selnolig` *per se*. To the best of my knowledge `selnolig` and `hyperref` are mutually independent. Does the file you're trying to compile load `hyperref` as well? Did `url.sty` maybe not get installed (or not get installed correctly?)

Comment: FWIW, we could remove `selnolig` from the manual you're trying to compile (I think it's not good to impose dependencies that aren't *really* necessary (such as `fontspec` for example).`selnolig` isn't essential to the `lilyglyphs` manual. But *if* there is something wrong with your installation (and somehow it looks like this) you'll surely want to get it right ;-)

Comment: This issue appears to have resolved itself somehow. I wish I knew what happened to make it go away, but I don't. The only thing I changed that I can think of is that I synchronized the package manager with the repository, but I thought it did that automatically whenever the package manager started...